# window.open and perform actions in console

Tags: javascript, window.open, js-scrollintoview

In my js code, on a button click, I want to open the site in new tab and scroll to the **selector's location**, and highlight it.

Individually, I am able to achieve it, but when I try to peace it together, the selector is not highlighting

Following is the snippet which is to run in websites console

Website :- https://careers.mestel.com/

```
#go to website
window.open('https://careers.mestel.com/');

#Scroll to the view where selector is present
document.querySelector('ppc-content[key="footer-mestelFooterContent11"]').scrollIntoView();

# Highlight the selector
css_highlight = document.querySelector('ppc-content[key="footer-mestelFooterContent11"]')
css_highlight.style.outline = '#FDFF47 solid 5px'
```

**Only window.open action is getting performed,** other actions are not getting perform. Please suggest how to inject remaining js code after window.open. The final expected result will be is as shown in the following image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because the code will continue to execute in the window that is currently running (not the new opened one). You can inject new code in a new window in this way (not the only way):

```
var newWindow = window.open('https://careers.mestel.com/');
var newScript = document.createElement('script');

function injectScript() {
    // The code to inject
}

newScript.innerHTML = injectScript.toString() + ';';
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(theScript);
```

Comment: did the following but its only opening a window
https://i.imgur.com/amc4TW3.png

Comment: there was an extra `'`

Comment: I am sorry but it was not happening...can u also please try with the below code
https://www.ideone.com/CINfos

Comment: seems that you can't inject script in this page from an external URL: https://imgur.com/Yv1BZdL